# Asp.net 5 (vNext) How to use active directory with System.DirectoryServices

Tags: asp.net-core

I m playing with VS 2015 and Asp.net 5 but I have an issue.

I am not able to use System.DirectoryServices in Asp.net 5.

Both using System.DirectoryServices and   DirectoryEntry test = new DirectoryEntry(); lines are not underlined with red  as an error but when I try to build solution I get error such

Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'DirectoryServices' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) ConsoleApp.ASP.NET Core 5.0 Program.cs 2

My default project.json was like

```
{
"version": "1.0.0-*",
"dependencies": {
},
"commands": {
    "run": "run"
},
"frameworks": {
    "aspnet50": {  },
    "aspnetcore50": {
        "dependencies": {
            "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-22231"
        }
    }
}
```

}

And I changed it as

```
{
"version": "1.0.0-*",
"dependencies": {
},
"commands": {
    "run": "run"
},
"frameworks": {
    "aspnet50": {  
        "frameworkAssemblies": {
            "System.DirectoryServices": ""
        }
    },
    "aspnetcore50": {
        "dependencies": {
            "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-22231"
        }
    }
}
```

}

My program.cs is

```
using System;
using System.DirectoryServices;
namespace ConsoleApp
{
public class Program
{
    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        DirectoryEntry test = new DirectoryEntry();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently Not all assemblies are supported for ASP.net Core. Your project.json file has both enable ASP.net core and ASP.net50.

If you remove aspnetcore50 from frameworks then your code will work.

```
 {
"version": "1.0.0-*",
"dependencies": {
},
"commands": {
    "run": "run"
},
"frameworks": {
    "aspnet50": {  
        "frameworkAssemblies": {
            "System.DirectoryServices": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running ASP.Net 5 RC 1, you will need to make the following changes in your project.json.

```
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.DirectoryServices": "4.0.0.0"
      },
      "dependencies": { }
    },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },
```

Comment: This does not work, when building I still get an error saying that System.DirectoryServices namespace does not exist for Core 5.0