# Should I Use Windows Authentication in ASP.NET 5?

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication

I am used to creating internal asp.net windows authentication applications that automatically populate a WindowsPrincipal that has claims about the username and some group information which I assume is coming from Active Directory. I installed Visual Studio 2015 and attempting an ASP.NET 5 web application but Windows Authentication is greyed out. I've been learning about claims based authentication and also understand the cross platform capabilities ASP.NET 5 will bring to the table and that I may need to get away from windows authentication.

This internal web application sits within an Active Directory domain though and I'd prefer not to have to ask the user for credentials if not needed since this will go on top of IIS. How **should** I get the current user? Do I need to choose a different authentication method and somehow get claims from AD through another method or is windows authentication still a recommended option for this scenario and will be made available eventually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't played around with v5 yet, but I use SSO using the windows identity in my Intranet apps. Have you tried GenericPrincipal? Now I'm curious and will need to speak with my employer about testing .NET 5...

Working with the GenericPrincipal and IIdentity, you can get anything out of active directory on the user logged into Windows.

This is all within my Employee class.

```
public Employee(Authenticate identity)
{
    if (identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        // if the account exists, build the employee object
        loadEmployee(identity as IIdentity);
    }
    else
    {
        // If the account cannot be found in Active Directory, throw an exception
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(identity.Name, "Employee does not exist");
    }
}

private void loadEmployee(IIdentity identity) 
{ 
    // the domain name of the identity
    string domain = identity.Name.Split('\\')[0];

    // the username of the identity
    string username = identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];

    // Initializes a new context for the identity's domain
    PrincipalContext domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain);

    // Initialize a principal using the domain context and the username of the identity
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, username);

    // Build a collection of all the underlying objects
    var userProperties = ((DirectoryEntry)user.GetUnderlyingObject()).Properties;

    // populate the employee objects properties
    LastName = user.Surname;
    FirstName = user.GivenName;
    NtUserName = username;
    GUID = user.Guid.ToString();
}
```

In my AuthenticationFilter class, I build my IPrincipal.

```
//build the system's Identity and Principal
var genIdentity = new GenericIdentity(employee.FirstName + " " + employee.LastName);
var genPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(genIdentity, roles[]);
var identity = (IPrincipal)genPrincipal;
context.User = identity;
```

Hopefully this is along the lines of what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I do something similar in 4.5 now and build a custom identity after receiving the initial identity from Windows Auth. I'm not using SSO. I can play with hacking asp.net 5 today to try and get windows auth to work but wanted to understand if I should be moving towards and alternate direction or if support will be built in.

Comment: Update: I selected "No Authentication" from the new project dialog window and then within the project properties under the Debug tab IIS Express Settings I unchecked anonymous auth and checked windows auth. After that, the new User and Context.User properties available from the Controller class automatically populate with the claims from AD that I'm used to seeing before letting IIS pass in the user's domain credentials to the app. I'm assuming I can still intercept the pipeline to create custom claims on top of that but am I using AD right? Are there identity features from AD I'm not using?

Comment: I just looked through GitHub's dotnet project and couldn't find the System.DirectoryServices assembly, which tells me that it isn't supported yet.  This SO response supports that thought. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28021962/755908.

So even though you set up your project for Windows Authentication, you won't be able to use custom claims using DirectoryServices in .Net 5. However, once enabled, you will be able to implement SSO using Active Directory.